# Fixed angle between two lines which are following the mouse

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

For a while I've been trying to implement this feature into my HTML5 Canvas using JavaScript. Here's an example picture:

[image: Here's an example picture.]

You can see above an example I just draw to help myself telling you what I'm trying to achieve.
What I'm trying to do is the following: There's a given X,Y coordinate on the canvas, this point is the fixed starting point of the two lines. The angle between the two lines should always be fixed, for example: 40°. The two lines should follow the mouse with a fixed angle between them. Searching the site I could achieve the following state of this feature:
Based on [this tutorial](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/) I could create the two lines that follow the mouse, and both lines' end points are always 100px far from the mouse, but, of course, that doesn't give me a fixed angle, the angle changes as I move the mouse around on the canvas.

Here's the part of my JS code that draws the two lines:

```
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(xcoord, ycoord);
  context.lineTo(ev._x+100, ev._y);
  context.stroke();
  context.closePath();

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(xcoord, ycoord);
  context.lineTo(ev._x-100, ev._y);
  context.stroke();
  context.closePath();
```

If I click with my mouse and I don't release the button, the two lines are following the mouse, that's why the `context.clearRect` part is there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I can't solve this problem by myself.

Comment: How should the angle be positioned in reference to the mouse coordinates? How long should the lines be?

Comment: That's my problem: the lines' lenght would vary depending on how far the pointer is from the lines's starting point. With fixed line length, make the angle fixed as well would not be a problem :)

Comment: But there is not much difference, ill write some code. Could you provide the wrapping code (canvase, listeners) somewhere so that I can generate an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, get the wanted line length:

```
var delta = {x: event.x - coord.x, y: event.y - coord.y};
var len = Math.sqrt(delta.x*delta.x + delta.y*delta.y);
```

Then get the angle (with [atan2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2)), and add the 40°:

```
var angle = Math.atan2(delta.y, delta.x);
var angle_left = angle + 40 / 180 * Math.PI;
var angle_right = angle - 40 / 180 * Math.PI;
```

Now you can get the points from this:

```
var left = {
    x: coord.x + Math.cos(angle_left) * len,
    y: coord.y + Math.sin(angle_left) * len
};
var right = {
    x: coord.x + Math.cos(angle_right) * len,
    y: coord.y + Math.sin(angle_right) * len
};
```

([Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/jhFSd/) - [Your fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/JpeVq/1/))

Comment: [Here's the wrapping code as you requested](http://jsfiddle.net/JpeVq/) This show's how would it look like in action, except, of course, the angle is not fixed in this one.
Right now I'm having a bit hard time of how could I implement your solution as I'm really unexperienced in JS. **edit**: I didn't notice your jsfiddle demo, thank you very much, that should help, since this is exactly what I'm trying to achieve :)

Comment: Your `img_update` throws errors, there is no `contexto`. If fixed, this will delete the image onMouseUp - the tutorial code uses two canvases and copies static elements onto the other one.

Comment: I didn't realize this until you said and checked it in the JS console, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

How about this then? : http://edumax.org.ro/extra/new/Stack2/

```
var canvas, ctx;

function viewDidLoad(){
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.height = 500;
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mouse_move_handler, false);
}


var px, py;

function mouse_move_handler(e){
var mouse = getCursorPosition(e);

var centreX = canvas.width/2;
var centreY = canvas.height/2;


var line = Math.sqrt( (mouse.y-centreY)*(mouse.y-centreY)+(mouse.x-centreX)*(mouse.x-centreX));

var k1 = 100;
var k2 = line-100;

var dx  =(mouse.x-centreX)/ line;
var dy = (mouse.y-centreY)/line;

var x1 = mouse.x+100*dy;
var x2 = mouse.x-100*dy;
var y1= mouse.y-100*dx;
var y2= mouse.y+100*dx;

if(line>=100){
px = ((k1*centreX) + (k2*mouse.x))/(k1+k2);
py = ((k1*centreY)+(k2*mouse.y))/(k1+k2);



canvas.width = canvas.width;
ctx.fillStyle="#00ffaa";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);

ctx.lineTo(px, py);
ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);

ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.strokeStyle = "Black";
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
}
}

// Get Current Mouse Position
function getCursorPosition(e) {
    var x, y;
    if (e.layerX || e.layerY) {
        x = e.layerX;
        y = e.layerY;
    }
    else {
        x = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        y = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }               
    return {x:x, y:y};
    }
window.onload = viewDidLoad;
```

Comment: @Laszlo Parazs What am I doing wrong here? I could easily change this but I am having trouble understanding exactly what you need.

Comment: I probably explained myself a bit wrong in the topic, because that's not exactly what I meant, see above for the solution. Anyway I really appreciate your effort, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? You can view a working example here: http://edumax.org.ro/extra/new/Stack1/

```
var canvas, ctx;

function viewDidLoad(){
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.height = 500;
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mouse_move_handler, false);
}

function mouse_move_handler(e){
var mouse = getCursorPosition(e);
canvas.width = canvas.width;
ctx.fillStyle="#00ffaa";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(mouse.x-100, mouse.y);
ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y+100);
ctx.lineTo(mouse.x+100, mouse.y);
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.strokeStyle = "Black";
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
}

// Get Current Mouse Position
function getCursorPosition(e) {
    var x, y;
    if (e.layerX || e.layerY) {
        x = e.layerX;
        y = e.layerY;
    }
    else {
        x = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        y = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }               
    return {x:x, y:y};
    }
window.onload = viewDidLoad;
```